# Device not booting from HDD

Tags: hardware-failure

Toshiba Satellite C855D-S5106 hard drive got crashed and after replacing it with a new one, whenever I boot on the laptop this is what appears on the screen;

> Checking Media [Fail] Checking Media.
>
> No bootable device -- Please restart system
>
> No bootable device -- Please restart system
>
> No bootable device -- Please restart system
>
> No bootable device -- Please restart system
>
> No bootable device -- Please restart system
>
> No bootable device -- Please restart system

This thing keeps repeating and am so frustrated.

Comment: What have you done with the new one? I suppose old one contained the system drive, so you need to reinstall OS to work.

Comment: Bro, I've done that several times but its still not working for me.

Comment: What have you done several times? How you could do that if your system doesn't start? Please update your question and explain what have your tried.

Comment: I installed an OS on to the hard drive using another PC. Of which I put it back into the Toshiba laptop but it still tells me "no bootable device--restart system"

Answer (score 1):

Your firmware shows "Checking Media" when trying to PXE-boot over the network (the message refers to initializing the Ethernet connection).

The reason it's trying to boot via PXE is because there is no boot entry for your operating system. UEFI systems have two ways of finding the boot device:

1. Boot entries in NVRAM, created during OS installation (NVRAM is part of the motherboard, and isn't carried over with the HDD);
2. Looking for a specific file at a specific location (`\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` in the EFI system partition) of each connected drive.

Because *both* methods have failed, it's likely that your disk contents aren't UEFI-compatible – the operating system was installed in BIOS mode.

#### If you installed on a BIOS system (or in BIOS mode)

On the new computer, look for "Legacy boot" or "CSM boot" in the firmware settings. Enabling this will activate support for BIOS-mode operating systems.

#### If you installed on in UEFI mode

Repair the bootloader using recovery media (e.g. the Windows install USB). For example, in Windows 10, assuming the recovery system detected your HDD as `C:`, you can use:

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```

...from the recovery "Command line" window. This will copy in new files *and* recreate the NVRAM entry, so that both of the above boot methods will start working.